# Не устанавливается виртуалка alpine через libvirt. Kernel Panic

Tags: kernel, kvm, виртуальная-машина, alpine-linux, init

Есть виртуалка с Debian 11, на нее пытаюсь поставить через libvirt виртуалку с alpine 3.13.

```
        virt-install --name vm-alpine3.13.5 \
        --cdrom /home/user/alpine-standard-3.13.5-x86.iso \
        --memory=1024 --vcpus=1 --disk size=4
```

Запускается установка и...[image: Kernel panic]

Почему так и как это решить, чтобы нормально установился alpine, в qemu он установился без проблем.

Comment: Предположу, что архитектуры процессоров хоста и виртуалки не совпадают... То есть, виртуалки пытается запускать среду через KVM, а quemu использует софтверную эмуляцию, которая работает ме-е-е-е-дленно, но которой вообще все равно, какой процессор на каком эмулировать

Comment: ryzen 5 2600, его архитектура x86_64, исошник скачан с официального сайта alpine и в нем написано x86, виртуалка дебиана amd64, моменты совместимости/несовместимости я пытался избежать делая все педантично, и вероятность, что дело в этом маловероятна. Но попробую данный вариант

Comment: В общем скорее всего беда в особенности работы KVM и VirtualBox, на хост машине на той же версии debian успешно установил alpine.

Comment: А "под чем" у Вас успешно установился alpine? То есть, что изменилось, относительно той конфигурации, которая в вопросе?

Answer (score 0):

Для работы виртуалки внутри виртуалки нужно настроить nested-virtualization
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/using-nested-virtualization-in-kvm/

Проверить поддерживается ли в файле /sys/module/kvm_amd/parameters/nested

Если нет, то покопаться в настройках биос и проверить ещё раз.

Если получлось, то в /etc/modprobe.d/kvm.conf файл на хосте:

```
options kvm_amd nested=1
```

П.С. по возможности никогда не делай вложенных виртуалок. Используй докер или lxc.